# How to make a smooth mouse movement in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a 2d unity game for a smartphone. The player swings right and left with the mouse. But the mouse movement is not smooth. That is, the player's turn is sharp and occurs when I click the mouse button. How do I make the movement smooth? Help please.
My code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class qwe : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float angle0ffset;
    public float direction = 1f; // initial direction
    public float speed = 20f; // speed of rotation

    
    void Update ()
     {
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))       
         {
    float angle = transform.eulerAngles.z;  
        if (angle > 180f) angle -= 360f; 

        if ((angle < -10f) || (angle > 10f)) direction *= -1f; // reverse direction (toggles between 1 & -1) 

        transform.Rotate (0, 0, speed * direction * Time.deltaTime);        
   }
          
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your users _want_ smoothing? It might look better to an onlooker, but it takes away precision from the user, and makes the controller feel like a rubber band.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make use of Quaternion.Slerp(). I found [this guy](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1697551/smoothly-rotating-an-object-to-a-specific-rotation.html) in Unity forums who asked a very similar question.